# How to automate the backup the single table in the Database

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I want to automate the process of backing up the single table from the database daily. 
how can I do that in sqlserver,

P.S - I don't have the sysadmin rights and so cannot use Sql Server Agent.

Comment: Backups work on entire databases, not tables. You don't need sysadmin rights to use SQL Server Agent. If you don't have writes to create a job, ask the DBA to do it for you. Are you sure you can perform a backup anyway? This requires additional permissions as well

Comment: So there is no way to automate the backup of a single table ?

Comment: There's no `backup of a single table` to automate. What are you asking? What do you want to do? *Copying* the data isn't a backup. *Copying changed rows* isn't backup either. Are you confusind backup with dumping a table's data? That's actually scripting of the data, not a backup

Comment: You *could* move the table to a separate filegroup and backup only that filegroup. If you can't even add a scheduled job though, you probably can't alter and move tables around.

Comment: I wanted to create a new table lets call it table_A_todaysdate and copy the date of  table_a into newly created table and delete the old created table, I wanted to automate this process.

Comment: If you are trying to create a table with the current date as part of the name chances are you need to rethink your process.

Comment: @dicerolling that's not backup. You don't need to create a new table either, just use partitions on the existing table. Define a partitioning scheme by date and save each partition in a different file. Partitioning is supported in *all* editions of SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later, even LocalDB. Before that, it was only available in Enterprise

Comment: @dicerolling BTW how many millions of rows do you have that you want to partition the data? If you *don't*, you have a design issue that should be solved instead of covered up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the SELECT INTO construct and some dynamic SQL to name it for the date:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000) =
'SELECT *
INTO YourTable_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) + '
FROM YourTable;'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

You will need an agent job to run it, or run it manually daily. Note that it will create a new table every day, so at some point you'll want to clean out old ones. It also doesn't create any indexes so queries will be slow, though you can include index generation in the dynamic sql.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with *backups* or even table data?

Comment: If the idea is to move data out from one table and into another, that's already available through partitioning. Starting with 2016 SP1 it's available in all editions. Before that it was only available in Enterprise. Given that partitions are only needed if you have *millions* of rows, it's not that strange.

Comment: Because the author isn't really looking for backups, they want a way to compare data changes over time. Backups are cold storage, this is hot storage. My assumption is that they're just using "backup" colloquially, not technically.

Comment: This answer doesn't show that at all. Besides, such functionality is *already* available

Comment: If one wanted to find the changes, there's no reason to move data anyway.  An outer join between tables, or use of change tracking which *is* available since 2005 for all editions would return the changes

Comment: Change tracking only tells you "something changed" - you need Auditing to actually track changes, and that's an Enterprise feature which I can't assume they have. My solution gives the author a snapshot of the table that they can keep as a reference and discard when they no longer need it, which is what I surmised they were looking for. I could be pedantic and tell them "don't do that", but instead I assume they have their reasons and give them their answer. If they want to do something horrible, I'll tell them "this is horrible, but here's how to do it". This isn't one of those times.